# Use Hudson to push changes to another SVN Repository

Tags: svn, hudson

I am working in a slightly unusual environment at the moment.  We are writing code on Ubuntu virtual machines, which cannot see our target SVN repository.

We are using a local SVN repository, which is polled by Hudson.

The Hudson env *can* see the target SVN repo.

So I'd like to use Hudson to push SVN changes from the local repo to the target repo, following a successful build.

I would need to retain the SCM history.  We will be the only ones committing into both repositories.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Thanks!
 - L

Comment: This sounds awfully much like a distributed VCS. You are aware that working on a local repo first and then pushing to a target repo is the reason d'etre of Git and Mercurial, don't you?

Comment: Yes, and I'd love to use Git!  Unfortunately I am restricted by my client's existing infrastructure...

Answer (score 1):

You can also attempt to use git local repositories and interface with that svn repository via git-svn. So Hudson will be operating on a git-svn clone (which you will push to from your git local repos), and by means of shell script, performing `git svn fetch|dcommit` from/to the svn repo.

Answer (score 0):

1. Hudson per se can not **push** any data, only *pull*, AFAIK
2. Hudson haven't Working Copy in terms of SVN (?)
3. I think, you *can try to configure job in Hudson*, which, on a successful build:

   - (prepare WE)
   - `svn co <DEVREPO> .` **OR** `svn up` (depending from above preparation)
   - `svn relocate <DEVREPO> <CLIENTREPO>`
   - `svn ci -m "Mirror revisions on build"`

(some options missing in my draft - config, authentifcation, non-interactive mode)